# Matlab: cell to file

Tags: arrays, matlab, file, loops, cell

I am trying to make a vertical histogram, where the user inputs 10 values and output shows as many '*' vertically corresponding to the 10 values.

so i have the array `narray`
narray =

```
narray = 

{1x10 cell}
{1x10 cell}
{1x10 cell}
{1x10 cell}
{1x10 cell}
{1x10 cell}
{1x10 cell}
{1x10 cell}
{1x10 cell}
{1x10 cell}
```

each cell contains a mixture of blank spaced cell   and `*` for eg

```
narray{2}
```

ans =

```
' '    '*'    ' '    '*'    ' '    '*'    ' '    '*'    ' '    '*'
```

I wanted to print each row of the cell to a file, i tried this

```
fid = fopen('star.txt','wt')

for i =1:10
    fprintf(fid,'%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s', narray{i});
end
fclose(fid);
type star.txt
```

but it shows error

```
Error using ==> fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.

Error in ==> test2 at 41
    fprintf(fid,'%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s', narray{i});
```

here is my full code,

```
n= cell(10,1);

%% // Taking input
for i = 1:10
prompt = 'Numbers bitch :  ';
n{i}{1} = input(prompt);
end
array =cell(10,1);


%% // Storing Input in cell
for i=1:10
    for j=1:10;
        array{i}{j} = ' ';
    end
end

for i = 1:10
    for j=1:n{i}{1}
        array{i}{j}='*';
    end
end

for i= 1:10;
array{i} = array{i}';
end

array=array';
narray=cell(10,10);
for i=1:10
    for j=1:10
        narray{i}{j} = array{j}{i};
    end
end
narray=narray(:,1);

%% // Printing Cell
fid = fopen('C:\Users\harsh\Documents\MATLAB\star.txt','wt')

for i =1:10
    fprintf(fid,'%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t\n', narray{i};
end
fclose(fid);
type star.txt
```

I am supposed to get output like this, for the input values
2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1

```
*********
* * * * *
```

Comment: Can you try replacing  `narray{i}` with `horzcat(narray{i}{:})`

Comment: @jucestain well the error has gone, but i am not getting the pattern i want, could you check my updated code

Comment: What's wrong with the output for `horzcat(narray{i}{:})`?

Comment: @jucestain, it gives me this `********** * * * * * `

Comment: i think there is some `\n` problem

Comment: i think i solved it :) thanks man!

Comment: My name is ra`y`ryeng :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: corrected syntax

A great code to do this is [cell2csv](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7601-cell2csv) so all you would need to do is say

```
cell2csv('star.txt', narray, '')
```

A better way to do your program without the loops though is

```
function writeHist(varargin)
    %% input hist
    if nargin == 0
        nInputs = input('Please enter number of inputs: ');
        n = zeros(nInputs,1);

        %% // Taking input
        for i = 1:nInputs
            n(i) = input(['Enter input ', num2str(i),': ']);
        end
    else
        n = varargin{1};

        if ~isvector(n) || ~isnumeric(n)
            disp({'Please either do not enter an input arguement or enter a vector'})
        end
    end

    % Prepare hist
    array = num2cell(cell2mat(arrayfun(@(i) [repmat('*', 1, i), repmat(' ', 1, max(n(:)) - i)], n(:), 'uni', 0)),1)';

    %% Printing hist
    cell2csv('star.txt', array, '')

end
```

So if we use your example

```
writeHist([2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1])
```

Contents of star.txt are

```
**********
* * * * *
```

Comment: Undefined function or method 'cell2csv' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Comment: You have to download the script. It's at the link.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this solved my problem

```
for i =1:10
    fprintf(fid,'%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t\n', vertcat(narray{i}{:}));
    fprintf(fid,'\n');
end
fclose(fid);
```